# codeigniter order by desc not working properly for more then 2 or 3 digits

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building an codeigniter web application, Like shop selling records. I want to show all record by order no., for this I try this query

```
SELECT * FROM (`az_orders`) ORDER BY `order_number` desc LIMIT ".$start.", ".$this->page_config['per_page'];
```

but it's getting wrong results, I want

```
999
.
.
990
989
988
```

but the query giving me

```
999
.
.
990
99
989
```

Please check screen shoot.
[image]

Comment: `order_number` is an integer field in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `order_number` column type to be int, it is varchar